# \selectlanguage pushes section to new page

Tags: page-breaking, babel, write

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\kant[1]
\begin{itemize}
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\end{itemize}
\kant[2]
\begin{itemize}
\item
\item
\item
\item
\end{itemize}

% \selectlanguage{ngerman}
\section{Baz}
\kant[1]

\end{document}
```

produces the output

[image]

When uncommenting the `\selectlanguage` instruction (and also using `\begin{otherlanguage}`) the second section is pushed to the second page. I noticed this in a document with `itemize`s in it, like I've shown here, and I did not manage to reproduce the problem by using text only.

My (wild) guess is that the *whatsit* node introduced by the `\write` directive issued by `\selectlanguage` interferes with the vertical glue introduced by  `itemize` and `\section`. In fact, writing

```
\makeatletter\write\@auxout{\relax}\makeatother
```

instead of `\selectlanguage` leads to the same problem.

Is my guess right? And more importantly, can I do something against it? In the real use case the section heading involves a `\...name` which changes with the language. As I workaround I could use `\foreignlanguage` in the section title but I'd like to know if there are better ways.

Comment: Yes, your guess is right.

Comment: I’ve opened and issue: https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/114

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your guess is right. At the end of `\end{itemize}`, an instruction

```
\addvspace{<skip 1>}
```

is issued and `\section` issues

```
\addvspace{<skip 2>}
```

so, in normal situations, only the greater skip results in the output. However, as you observe, the `\write` instruction that's part of `\selectlanguage` makes it impossible for the second `\addvspace` to know the amount of `<skip 1>`, because the last item in the vertical list is no longer a vertical skip.

You can manually fix this with

```
\setlength{\skip0}{\lastskip}
\addvspace{-\skip0}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\addvspace{\skip0}
```

which works for the *particular* situation.

### Output without the four above lines

Note the correct English hyphenation of “representation”.

[image]

### Output with the four lines above

Note the incorrect English hyphenation of “representation” (due to using German hyphenation rules).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Luckily the "particular situation" is very close to what I'll always have (it's for a multi-lingual exercise sheet, and this combination itemize/section is built in) so I can adapt your solution to my case.

Answer (score 6):

`hyperref` tries quite hard to avoid such side effects. You could steal its commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\kant[1]
\begin{itemize}
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\end{itemize}
\kant[2]
\begin{itemize}
\item
\item
\item
\item
\end{itemize}


\makeatletter
\Hy@SaveLastskip
\selectlanguage{english}
\Hy@RestoreLastskip
\makeatother


\section{Baz}

\kant[1]

\end{document}
```

(It is not perfect, in some cases it then suppress a break point).

Comment: Wow, that's also a great answer. I'll try it out.